# how to imitate a link click in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt4

Actualy, i have different tabs.
what I wanted to achieve is, 
- user clicked a link from tab 1
- and it will immediately display QTextBrowser in tab 2, at the html anchor i set.

Is there a way of doing this?

I've managed to switch tab by using tabWidget.setCurrentWidget()
now the question is, how to set the focus to the desired html anchor place of the QTextBrowser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the documentation of `QTextBrowser`: If a document name ends with an anchor (for example, "#anchor"), the text browser automatically scrolls to that position (using scrollToAnchor()). When the user clicks on a hyperlink, the browser will call setSource() itself with the link's href value as argument. You can track the current source by connecting to the sourceChanged() signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
from tabwidget import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self._show)

    def _show(self):
        self.ui.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.tab_2)
        self.ui.textBrowser.setSource(QtCore.QUrl('text.html#anchor'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyApp()
    mw.show()
    app.exec_()
```